# Не могу поставить mysqlclient для Python 3

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, pip

Пытаюсь поставить mysqlclient через pip3 для Python 3.6.0

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in <listcomp>
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/
```

Установка mysql-connector-c тоже не помогла

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Comment: на Ubuntu установка работает: 1- `sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev` 2- `pip install mysqlclient` Убедитесь, что вы поставили необходимые зависимости для вашей системы (которую в вопросе следует упомянуть). См. https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

Comment: При установке как раз таки следовал мануалу на https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python
не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема.
Удалите mysql-connector-c, затем сделайте следующее:

```
brew install mysql
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Чтобы удалить mysql-connector-c:

```
brew uninstall mysql-connector-c
```